# Flying to the US without an ESTA

Tags: visas, usa, us-visa-waiver-program

I have a British passport and live in the UK. I was visiting Canada a few weeks ago and crossed the border (by car) to the US and got a 90 day visa.

I am now back in the UK but the visa is still in my passport (it wasn't removed at the border).

On the [ESTA application website](https://esta.cbp.dhs.gov/esta/) it says one is not eligible to apply for an ESTA if they are currently in possession of a visitor's visa.

Will I be okay if fly there with my current visa?

EDIT: I should mention, I have a visitor's visa, but this new trip will be for work purposes

Comment: Does your visa allow re-entries other than across the Canada land-border? If yes, you are good. If no, it is not valid and you need an ESTA.

Comment: I believe the visa I have allows for  multiple entries

Comment: By work, do you mean business? BIG difference, as you need totally different papers for work

Comment: @Crazydre yes I mean for business!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**What you got at the border is NOT a visa.**

You were *admitted* at a land border crossing point as a Visa Waiver Program traveler, in WT status. To document this status you got an admission stamp in your passport and possibly also a paper I-94W form -- but neither of these is a visa. Visas are issued by embassies/consulates *in advance* of traveling, not by border crossing points.

Your WT status terminated automatically when you left the US, but it is *possible* that your departure has not been recorded in the CBP systems, especially if you left by land without handing back your I-94W. To check whether your departure has been recorded, go to https://i94.cbp.dhs.gov/I94/ and search for yourself by name, passport number and DOB.

In any case, having been admitted in WT status does *not* disqualify you for applying for an ESTA.

Comment: If you're sure I'm mistaken and what you have is actually a visa, please update the question with a photo/scan of the visa, with personal info blacked out.

Comment: Thank you for the information. From that link, I can see that my departure from the US was not recorded -- will this cause an issue for me re-entering?

Comment: @Prash: There is a somewhat clunky process for sending proof that you have left the US by post to some address, so it will not look like you overstayed. However, if your next trip will be _completed_ within the original 90-day admission period, I think I would just leave the the old I-94W in your passport and point it out to the border officer when you land, asking what is the right thing to do. Then the worst thing that could realistically happen is that you're re-admitted just until the original leave-by date. (You'll still need to apply for an ESTA before flying, of course).

Comment: Alternatively, the official recommendation is to travel with documentation that you were actually present outside the US after your unrecorded departure. Non-US passport stamps from after you left, boarding cards, or relevant receipts/bills/payslips from your life in the UK will be useful.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I think I'll keep the I94 in my passport and travel with the relevant documentation!

Comment: "does not disqualify you for applying for an ESTA" Don't you mean "does not excuse you from the requirement to apply for an ESTA"?

Comment: @DavidRicherby: It doesn't do _that_ either, but I was responding to the OP's apparent fears that he couldn't apply for ESTA while having an apparently-open I-94W.